# Java unreported exception in socket connection

Tags: java, sockets, javac

I am learning java and I am getting an odd error I do not understand, below is my code:

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.IOException;
class Client{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println("Connecting...");
        Socket request=new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1234);
        System.out.println("Connected.");
        request.close();
    }
}
```

The error in which I am receiving:

```
test.java:6: error: unreported exception UnknownHostException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        Socket request=new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1234);
                   ^
1 error
```

I am using javac test.java to compile if it helps, anyone know how to rectify this error?

Comment: must be caught - well, try-catch it?

Comment: which OS are you on? check your host IP address and use it

Comment: @Worthless Oh ROFL, thank  you, I am very new to java, After I do this it compiles with no error, but no test file shows up to run? Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can implement this either you write `throws UnknownHostException` behind you main method or you surround this with a try-catch. But it would be much more clever to write IOException instead od UnknownHostException because you need to implement this later on anyway and because UnknownHostException extends IOException you can just write `throws IOException`

#### Method 1:

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{
    System.out.println("Connecting...");
    Socket request=new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1234);
    System.out.println("Connected.");
    request.close();
}
```

#### Method 2:

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    System.out.println("Connecting...");
    try {
        Socket request=new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1234);
        System.out.println("Connected.");
        request.close();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation `public Socket(String host, int port) throws UnknownHostException, IOException` throws

```
UnknownHostException - if the IP address of the host could not be determined.
```

make sure you pass the correct IP address

Answer (score 1):

Using try-with-resources lets you not have to worry about closing stuff if something goes wrong. Catch the exception if there are one, then the socket is automaticly closed.

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.IOException;
class Client{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println("Connecting...");
        try (Socket request=new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1234)){
            System.out.println("Connected.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Host error:" + e)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now there is one.